# SQL - Position in statistics

Tags: sql, sqlite, statistics, position

For example, I have table with columns:

```
playerName TEXT,
score INTEGER
```

And I have 10,000 rows in this table.
Now I can select e.g. top 100 players by using simple SQLite query:

```
SELECT playerName FROM table ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 100
```

And now I have a question: how I can get position in statistics of player X which is not in top100?
I can do this by selecting all rows and then in a loop find position of player X but I think it doesn't have a good performance.
Is a simpler way to do this in SQLite and MySQL?

Comment: Why are you asking about MySQL if you are currently using SQLite?

Comment: I'll probably migrate my databse to MySQL in future but at the moment I'm using SQLite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count how many players with larger score there are:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM MyTable
WHERE score >= (SELECT score
                FROM MyTable
                WHERE playerName = 'X');
```

(If you want to know this for all players, a single query would be more efficient.)

Comment: Thanks, but what do you think about making a new column "position INTEGER" and update it every 1 hour for all players? Is it possible to do it with a single query?

Comment: In what situation would this be an improvement?

Comment: I'll probalby have to check often position in ranking of some players so maybe it's better to add special column for it and update it e.g every 1h to get faster player's position.

Comment: An index on `playerName` and an index on `score` would make this query fast without have to maintain them manually.